# Trying to use VTK-6.3.0 and Qt-4.8.5 with QtCreator-4.1 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, qt4, windows-10, qt-creator, qvtkwidget

For a project I need to use VTK and Qt (with QtCreator on C++) on Windows 10 but I have an issue.

Let me explain what I've done before going further:

- I Install **QtCreator-4.1** with **MinGW 32bit** and Qt-5.7
- I download and install **Qt-4.8.5** in the Qt directory (It isn't proposed in the QtCreator's MaintenanceTool)
- I download **VTK-6.3.0**
- I compile VTK with QtCreator (and a kit with Qt4) on Release with *BUILD_SHARED_LIBS = True* and *VTK_Group_Qt = True*

Then, I use an example and the CMakeLists.txt my teacher gave me, using Qt and VTK, but I have an error:

> cannot find -lQVTK

In this code we use:

```
#include <QVTKWidget.h>
```

In my build directory I find : "libQVTKWidgetPlugin.dll.a" and "libQVTKWidgetPlugin.dll".

Here is the CMakeLists.txt I used (it was written for Linux user, but I'm not enough experienced to change it...):

```
project(foot)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Where I built VTK
set(VTK_DIR "C:/Lib/VTK/build-VTK-6.3.0-Desktop_Qt_4_8_5_MinGW_32bit-Release")
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

set( Srcs main.cpp mainwindow.cpp )
set( Hdrs mainwindow.h )
set( MOC_Hdrs mainwindow.h )

# Use the include path and library for Qt that is used by VTK.
include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

if(VTK_QT_VERSION VERSION_GREATER "4")
  find_package(Qt5Widgets)
  qt5_wrap_ui(UI_Srcs)

  add_executable(qtevents
    MACOSX_BUNDLE  ${Srcs} ${Hdrs} ${MOC_Hdrs})
  qt5_use_modules(qtevents Core Gui Widgets)
  target_link_libraries(qtevents ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
  include(${QT_USE_FILE})
  # Use what VTK built with
  set(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE ${VTK_QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE} CACHE FILEPATH "")
  set(QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE ${VTK_QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE} CACHE FILEPATH "")
  set(QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE ${VTK_QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE} CACHE FILEPATH "")
  qt4_wrap_cpp(MOCSrcs ${MOC_Hdrs})

  add_executable(foot ${Srcs} ${Hdrs} ${MOC_Hdrs})
  target_link_libraries(foot ${VTK_LIBRARIES} QVTK)
endif()
```

I really don't understand what I've done wrong and my teacher can't help me...
If you have any idea...
I would be glad to give you more info if needed!